# Rails minitest with namespaced fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I have a namespaced model, namely `Billing::Plan`. So I put its fixture under `test/fixtures/test/billing/plan.yml`. (Actually, it was the rails generator to put it there, so I assumed it was a *convention over configuration* pleasantness :-))

Now, when I run a single test it works, but when I try to run all my test suite with `rake test` or `guard` the fixture loading fails with this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "plans" does not exist
```

The important part is

```
ERROR:  relation "plans" does not exist
```

It seems like the `fixtures :all` command in my `test_helper.rb` file fails to understand that the relation name is `billing_plans` instead of `plans`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out looking at what `fixtures :all` [does](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb).

It needs a call to `set_fixture_class` in order to correctly assign the table name to a namespaced fixture.

So I solved my problem adding...

```
# test/test_helper.rb

module ActiveSupport
  class TestCase
    fixtures :all
    set_fixture_class 'billing/plan' => Billing::Plan # <= ...this line!
 end
end
```