# How to set up namespaced model fixtures in Rails 7 Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, namespaces, fixtures, minitest

I've a similar issue like [this old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367232/rails-minitest-with-namespaced-fixtures) related to using namespaced model fixtures for a has_one-belongs_to association in Rails 7.

About ActiveRecord, in my model files I've:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :setting, :class_name  => 'Users::Setting', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
end

# app/models/users/setting.rb
class Users::Setting < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, :class_name  => 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
end

# app/models/users.rb
module Users
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'users_'
  end
end
```

About fixtures, in the test/fixtures/users.yml file I've created and successfully used the following for the User model:

```
# test/fixtures/users.yml

foo:
  id: 1
  name: Foo
  email: foo@bar.com
  ...

bar:
  id: 2
  name: Bar
  email: bar@foo.com
  ...
```

However I'm in trouble in setting up fixtures for the Users::Setting model. I tried to create the test/fixtures/users/settings.yml file and to use the following without success:

```
# test/fixtures/users/settings.yml

_fixture:
  model_class: Users::Setting

foo_setting:
  id: 1
  user_id: 1
  ...

# foo_setting:
#   id: 1
#   user: foo
#   ...
```

When I run a test, I get errors as follows:

> Minitest::UnexpectedError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table
> "users" has no columns named "user_id"/"user".

In the User fixtures I also tried to use the following but I get the same Minitest error:

```
# test/fixtures/users.yml

foo:
  id: 1
  name: Foo
  email: foo@bar.com
  setting: foo_setting (Users:Setting) # <<<
  ...
```

I also tried to edit the test/test_helper.rb file like so but I get the same Minitest error:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
  set_fixture_class 'users/settings' => Users::Setting
end
```

In test/integration/user_flows_test.rb I've:

```
# test/integration/user_flows_test.rb

require "test_helper"

class UserFlowsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  fixtures :users

  test "can something" do
    user = users(:foo)
    ...
  end
end
```

How can I state working fixtures for the namespaced Users::Setting?

Comment: You should use explicit nesting `module Users; class Setting ...` when defining nested constants. Using the scope resolution operator `::` leads to all kinds of weird and suprising constant lookups and behaviors and as it doesn't set the correct module nesting. https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition

Comment: Alternatively when you're using Zeitwerk you can omit the outer module and it will implicitly nest it according the to folder structure. For example if you have `class Baz; end` in `app/foo/bar/baz.rb` it will automatically create the `Foo` and `Bar` modules and you get `Foo::Bar::Baz`. Explicit nesting is generally prefereable though.

Comment: @max I tried to do explicit nesting in app/models/users/setting.rb (I updated the question) but the fixtures still do not work.

Comment: It will save you from a lot of potential future headaches though.

Comment: I can imagine, but until now I never had problems with namespacing.

Comment: Then you haven't been using it right. Half of the point is that you can refer to other constants in the same namespace without explicitly providing the path to them. You can for example do `has_many :foos` instead of `has_many :foos, class_name: 'Bar::Foo'`.

Comment: FYI Namespacing I'm using is also generated by rails scaffolding. BTW I prefer to be explicit wherever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

1. In test/test_helper.rb I added `set_fixture_class :users_settings => Users::Setting`

test/test_helper.rb

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  ...

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Namespaced models/fixtures
  set_fixture_class :users_settings => Users::Setting

  ...
end
```

2. (Re)Named the file that contains the fixture statement as *users_settings*.yml
3. Located the file *users_settings*.yml at test/fixtures/users_settings.yml